# Using Objects in Java Menu

Tags: java, object, methods

Here is my Main.java class

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int roomNum=0;
        Room[] myHotel = new Room[10];
        for (int x =0; x<10; x++){
           myHotel[x] = new Room(); 
        }

        String roomName;

        String menu;
        do { 

        System.out.println("Please Select an Option from the Menu:");
        System.out.println("Enter D to Delete Customer from Room");
        System.out.println("Enter Q to Quit");
        menu=input.next();
        if(menu.charAt(0) == 'D')deleteCustomer(myHotel[]);
        } while (menu.charAt(0) != 'Q');

            while (roomNum < 10) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++ )
             if (myHotel[x].getName().equals("e"))System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");

       }
    }
     public void deleteCustomer(String myHotelRef){
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please Enter Room Number to Delete Customer");
         int deleteRoom=input.nextInt();
         myHotelRef[deleteRoom].setName("e");
    }

}
```

Here is my Room.java class

```
public class Room {
    private String mainName;
    int guestsInRoom;

    public Room() {
        mainName = "e";
        System.out.println("made a room ");
    }

    public void setName(String aName) {
        System.out.println("add name class method ");
        mainName = aName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mainName;
    }

}
```

I get the following errors:

> unexpected type   required: value   found:    class
>
> '.class' expected

on the menu if statement

and

> array required, but String found

in the deleteCustomer method

Answer (score 0):

Java supports `a[b]` syntax only for arrays, but you're trying to apply it to `String` here: `myHotelRef[deleteRoom]`.

Answer (score 0):

This : `public void deleteCustomer(String myHotelRef)` means, that your method is called `deleteCustomer`, it has one parameter called `myHotelRef`, and that parameter is `String`. Therefore you cannot use method like this on String `myHotelRef[deleteRoom].setName("e");`

This should work : `public void deleteCustomer(Room[] myHotelRef)`

---

Also, here `Room[] myHotel = new Room[10];`, you defined `myHotel` variable as `array of Hotel`. Therefore if you use it, you does not have to use `[]`, if you pass all the array. You should use this : `deleteCustomer(myHotel)` instead of this : `deleteCustomer(myHotel[])`

---

And you forget to add `static` to your delete method.

---

This is working code :

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int roomNum=0;
        Room[] myHotel = new Room[10];
        for (int x =0; x<10; x++){
           myHotel[x] = new Room(); 
        }

        String roomName;

        String menu;
        do { 

        System.out.println("Please Select an Option from the Menu:");
        System.out.println("Enter D to Delete Customer from Room");
        System.out.println("Enter Q to Quit");
        menu=input.next();
        if(menu.charAt(0) == 'D')deleteCustomer(myHotel);
        } while (menu.charAt(0) != 'Q');

            while (roomNum < 10) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++ )
             if (myHotel[x].getName().equals("e"))System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");

       }
    }
     public static void deleteCustomer(Room[] myHotelRef){
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please Enter Room Number to Delete Customer");
         int deleteRoom=input.nextInt();
         myHotelRef[deleteRoom].setName("e");
    }
}
```